# Pure Javascript - custom js css selector for timed actions

Tags: javascript, css

So I have the following code:

```
function moveIt(var1,var2,var3){
    document.getElementById(var1).style.var2 = var3;
}
```

And then call it using

```
window.setTimeout("moveIt('square','backgroundColor','blue')",1500);
```

But it stays the same. Changin var2 to backgroundColor in the first code makes it work.

What can I do to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic object property name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamic-object-property-name)

Comment: You need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators): `….style[var2]`. And don't pass strings to [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout), pass functions!

Comment: Solved. Thanks. Still Learning!

Comment: @user2075203:remove that solved from title..just accept the answer you think is correct..

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 document.getElementById(var1).style[var2] = var3;
```

It's an applied version of [this concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamic-object-property-name).

Answer (score 2):

try

```
window.setTimeout(function(){moveIt('square','backgroundColor','blue')},1500);
```

with

```
function moveIt(var1,var2,var3){
    document.getElementById(var1).style[var2] = var3;
}
```